# Prove that $T$ is compact $\iff$ dim ran $T < \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

If we have the linear operator $T : X \rightarrow X$ is bounded and satisfies $T^2 = T$.

Then I have to prove that $T$ is compact $\iff$ dim ran $T < \infty$.

For $\leftarrow$ I was thinking of:

We have that $T$ has finite rank, then Im$T$ is a finite-dimensional normed space. Furthermore, for any bounded sequence $\{ x_n \}$ in $X$, the sequence $\{ T x_n \}$ is bounded in Im$T$, and since Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem stated that each bounded sequenc has a convergent subsequence. I think we can conclude that $T$ is compact.

But I could use some help for $\rightarrow$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For $\rightarrow:$ let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $ker(I-T).$ Hence $Tx_n=x_n.$ Since $T$ is compact, $(Tx_n)=(x_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence. Therefore $ker(I-T)$ has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property. Thus $ \dim ker(I-T) < \infty.$

Since $T^2=T$, we have $ran( T)=ker(I-T).$ This gives $ \dim ran(T) < \infty.$

Answer (score 1):

If $T^2=T$, then $\left. T\right\rvert_{\operatorname{ran}T}:(\operatorname{ran}T,\lVert \cdot\rVert)\to (\operatorname{ran}T,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$ is a bijective isometry and therefore, by Riesz lemma, the set $T\left(B_X(0,1)\cap\operatorname{ran}T\right)=T\left(B_{\operatorname{ran}T}(0,1)\right)=B_{\operatorname{ran}T}(0,1)$ won't be totally bounded unless $\dim\operatorname{ran}T<\aleph_0$.

"Continuous of finite rank implies compact" is a standard result that you may find in any book: namely, you may use your favourite formulation of the fact that in $\Bbb R^n$ totally bounded subsets and bounded subsets are the same, and the image of the ball by a continuous operator is bounded.